# MacOSX Python3 Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Python 3.7.0

there is a strange mystery with my mac:

when doing something as simple as a `brew install macvim` I get the below popup

[image]

The operation (`brew install macvim`) succeeds, but I keep getting these popups.

I don't have parental controls enabled.

`$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin 
drwxrwxr-x  685 myuser  admin  23290 Aug  6 12:21 /usr/local/bin`

File Permissions ...

```
lrwxrwxr-x  1 myuser  admin  34 Aug  6 11:03 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3

lrwxrwxr-x  1 myuser  admin  55 Aug  6 11:03 /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

-rwxrwxr-x  1 myuser  admin  13620 Aug  6 11:03 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7

lrwxrwxr-x  1 myuser  admin  9 Aug  6 11:03 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -> python3.7

-rwxrwxr-x  1 myuser  admin  13620 Aug  6 11:03 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
```

Comment: Probably not your issue, but… did you use `sudo` with `brew`, and also install Homebrew on an older OS X and then later upgrade both the OS and Homebrew? Because I’ve seen that symptom caused by doing that.

Comment: Or, did you install Python 3 from a Python.org installer using a different account from the one you’re using now?

Comment: installed python 3.7 from homebrew

Did not use sudo for installation

Comment: Well, I didn't think it was your issue, just ruling out the possibility that you were as dumb as me. :)

Comment: Next, what happens if you just type `python3` at the shell? And can you `ls -ld` both `$(which python3)` (presumably that's `/usr/local/bin/python3`) and the same on whatever the symlink points to (something in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/…`)?

Comment: python3 brings up the python3 shell 


```---
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3 lrwxrwxr-x
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 lrwxrwxr-x
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -rwxrwxr-x
/usr/local/bin/python3 lrwxrwxr-x
```

Comment: Just to rule out one more stupid thing: you are running as `myuser`, and `myuser` is an administrative user, right?

Comment: Correct. I'm running as `myuser` and nobody else's account